# Declare Variable of Child Class Type in Abstract Class

Tags: c#, inheritance

I would like to enforce that a function in a child class is the type of the class from the abstract parent. For example:

```
abstract class Animal {
    public abstract void Add(Animal animal);
}

class Cat: Animal {
    public override void Add(Cat cat) {
        //Do cat things
    }
}

class Dog: Animal {
    //This should not be allowed
    public override void Add(Animal dog) {
        //Do dog things
    }
}
```

Here we see that a `Cat` type object could be passed to `Dog.Add`. Is there a way to enforce the function to take type `Dog`?

I believe there are ways for it to be checked at run time, but I would much rather have a compiler error if possible.

Comment: That is not possible because if you do this then child class would not implement Add method from Animal Class. When you declare abstract method in base class then this method must be implemented in child classes. can you specify what is your requirement and why you want to do this?

Comment: Hmm, that's a good point. I'm providing an abstract `Effect` class for users which will have some methods which are meant to take other instances of the same class. Though, since the users are defining the methods, I suppose there could be use cases where the user might want different types of `Effects` passed through.

Answer (score 1):

You might declare an interface and use generics with a *where* constraint.

```
public abstract class Animal
{
}

public interface IAnimalCollection<T> where T : Animal
{
    void Add<T>(T animal);
}

public class Cat : Animal, IAnimalCollection<Cat>
{
    public void Add(Cat animal)
    {
    }
}

public class Dog : Animal, IAnimalCollection<Dog>
{
    // won't compile
    public void Add(Animal animal)
    {
    }
}

public class Ferret : IAnimalCollection<Ferret>
{
    public void Add(Ferret animal)
    {
    }

    public void Add(Animal animal)
    {
    }
}

// won't compile
public class Foo : IAnimalCollection<Foo>
{
    public void Add(Foo animal)
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem is that `public class Cat: Animal, IAnimalCollection<Dog>` would still be valid.

Comment: Perhaps I wanted to implement a Dog-catching Cat!

Comment: If each of your Effect sub-classes have different behaviors you should encapsulate those behaviors into interfaces instead of into the base class.